# Can you call a second constructor without an overload method

Tags: c#, json, constructor, linq-to-json

So I have a query. It's not really a problem as the code still works but it seems sloppy.

I need to have two constructors.

```
public class JsonQuery
{
    const string currentWorkSheet = "GLHTanneryData_CurrentWeek";
    const string unitTestingWorkSheet = "GLHTanneryData_UnitTesting";
    private const string authorisation = "XXXX";
    JObject jObject;

    public JsonQuery()
    {
        SmartsheetQuery smartsheetQuery = new SmartsheetQuery();
        jObject = JObject.Parse(smartsheetQuery.getJsonAsString(currentWorkSheet));
    }

    public JsonQuery(bool testing)
    {
        SmartsheetQuery smartsheetQuery = new SmartsheetQuery();
        jObject = JObject.Parse(smartsheetQuery.getJsonAsString(unitTestingWorkSheet));
    }
}
```

Each grabs a json file from a different location on smartsheets. So in order to call the second constructor I just feed it a boolean value of true. Thing is, and as you can see from the code, I don't actually need to use any boolean value in the method I just needed to know that it was this constructor I wanted to call.

Is there a nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need two constructors - it looks like you would benefit from passing in your worksheet:

```
 public JsonQuery(string worksheet)
 {
    SmartsheetQuery smartsheetQuery = new SmartsheetQuery();
    jObject = JObject.Parse(smartsheetQuery.getJsonAsString(worksheet));    
 }
```

Just pass in a different worksheet for testing.

Answer (score 2):

Something else you might consider is setting up a compiler directive for testing

```
public JsonQuery()
{
    SmartsheetQuery smartsheetQuery = new SmartsheetQuery();
#if TEST
    jObject = JObject.Parse(smartsheetQuery.getJsonAsString(unitTestingWorkSheet));
#else
    jObject = JObject.Parse(smartsheetQuery.getJsonAsString(currentWorkSheet));
#endif
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what a compiler directive is?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your class violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), it is both determining the data and parsing it.

In your situation this problem is making it very difficult to test the parsing mechanism as they're intertwined in the class.

An alternative would be to have the parsing class depend on some sort of data provider interface.

```
public interface ISmartSheetProvider
{
    string GetJsonData();
}

public class ProductionSmartSheetProvider : ISmartSheetProvider
{
    public string GetJsonData()
    {
        return new SmartsheetQuery().getJsonAsString("GLHTanneryData_CurrentWeek"));
    }
}

public class MockSmartSheetProvider : ISmartSheetProvider
{
    public string GetJsonData()
    {    
        return "..."; // whatever test data.
    }
}

public class JsonQuery(ISmartSheetProvider smartSheetProvider)
{
    jObject = jObject.Parse(smartSheetProvider.GetJsonData());
}
```

Though since all the work is done in the constructor, you may be better off just to provide it as a string or turn the whole class into a static method.  I'm assuming some code is omitted here and will assume the class does more than what is provided.

Comment: Hi Matt, I really appreciate this but I was intending on moving the string for the data outside of the class into a config file.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this do:

```
public JsonQuery(bool testing = false)
{
    SmartsheetQuery smartsheetQuery = new SmartsheetQuery();

    if (testing)
         jObject = JObject.Parse(smartsheetQuery.getJsonAsString(unitTestingWorkSheet));
    else
         jObject = JObject.Parse(smartsheetQuery.getJsonAsString(currentWorkSheet));
}
```

Then for non-testing you just need to initialize with `new JsonQuery()`

Answer (score 0):

It's called constructor chaining or nesting:

```
public JsonQuery() : this(false) // or true
{
}

public JsonQuery(bool testing) // or optional parameter value
{
    // use 'testing' here
}
```